# Error too big to serialize within the provided gas bounds. Increasing the gas bounds does not help

Tags: michelson, gas, bigmap

I am developing a fairly large set of contracts that interact with each other. I wanted to reorganize and optimized the code and I've added lots of `PUSH string "..."; FAILWITH` to help me debug. I am pushing the contracts to the alphanet so I can try calling them and make sure they interact properly.

After making some changes, I originated the contracts and tried calling them.

`~/alphanet.sh client transfer 0 from alice to test1 --arg 'Right 1' --burn-cap 1`

And I received the following message, but without any clue of which line is failing.

```
      Transaction:
        ...
        This operation FAILED.
...
Error too big to serialize within the provided gas bounds.
Gas limit exceeded during typechecking or execution.
Try again with a higher gas limit.
Fatal error:
  transfer simulation failed
```

I looked up how to increase the gas bounds with `~/alphanet.sh client transfer man`.

```
-G --gas-limit <amount>
```

I called the contract again with a large amount of gas `~/alphanet.sh client transfer 0 from alice to test1 --arg 'Right 1' --burn-cap 1 -G 9999999999999999999999`

but I receive the same error. Any ideas how I can get a more detailed error message?

EDIT: My guess is that it has something to do with big map. I moved some things in store that were originally maps into a big map.

Comment: You cannot set the gas limit higher than the hard_gas_limit_per_operation. However, try using `tezos-client run script ... --trace-stack -G $GAS`. With this command you can see the gas usage at each step, and you can set the gas limit as high as you want. Your error looks a little suspicious to me, but I don't know the cause, unless it is just normal gas exhaustion.

Comment: Can you try again on the carthagenet test network? The gas costs and limits have significantly changed twice since you asked this question.